# Adding a Vertex to a libgdx Mesh

Tags: android, libgdx

the title basically.

You can reserve more than you need when creating a mesh

```
mesh = new Mesh(false, 100, 0, new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"));
```

But there is no method for adding a vertex. You can get the FloatBuffer and add to that, but I get strange results. I also tried the mesh.setVertices with offset but that does not work either.

I debugged with drawing points. Works until I try adding a vertex by any means (even if I tweak offsets to account for 3 floats in one vertex)

Copied code segment:

```
mesh.setVertices(new float[] {
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0,
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0/*,
                -0.5f,0.5f,0.f*/});//works if I uncoment this
mesh.setVertices(new float[]{-0.5f,0.5f,0.f}, 6, 3);//but comment this out
```

I also tried

```
squareMesh.setVertices(new float[]{-0.5f,0.5f,0.f}, 2, 3);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding is a bad idea because the underlying buffers must be recreated and that takes up a lot of time. Instead, one should allocate meshes in bulk and only render what is currently used.

For example `mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,0,num_triangles);`

As for updating the buffer:

```
FloatBuffer fbuftmp = mesh.getVerticesBuffer(); 
BufferUtils.copy(buf,fbuftmp,fbuftmp.capacity(),0);
```

Where `buf` is an float array.

Use BufferUtils.copy for reason explained [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wiki/index.php/Direct_Bulk_FloatBuffer.put_is_slow)

Comment: Link is dead.. Could've been useful to me.

Comment: @RobotRock [Working link from archive.](https://web.archive.org/web/20130224002153/http://www.badlogicgames.com/wiki/index.php/Direct_Bulk_FloatBuffer.put_is_slow)