# "Flexible" meshes in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

In my app I need to generate various geometric objects.
For example, I can create a box with BoxShapeBuilder in coordinates 
{{1,1,1}, {1,-1,1}, {-1,-1,1}, {-1,1,1},
{1,1,-1}, {1,-1,-1}, {-1,-1,-1}, {-1,1,-1}}. 
Then, it's possible to scale, rotate it, and it's ok.
But, if I want to transform object's shape to 
{{2,2,1}, {1,-1,1}, {-1,-1,1}, {-1,1,1},
{1,1,-1}, {1,-1,-2}, {-1,-1,-1}, {-1,1,-1}}, or something similar. Is it possible to do without recreating the model ? 
Now, I need to create a new model, and it's very bad for performance.
i'm new in 3d programming, and maybe just don't know, what to search for. I assume there must be some simple trick to handle that problem.
Here is the sample code of the thing I want to do:

```
private class MyScreen implements Screen {
    ModelBatch modelBatch;
    PerspectiveCamera camera3d;

    ModelBuilder modelBuilder;
    Material boxMaterial;
    Environment environment;
    Model boxModel = null;

    float mult = 0f;

    Vector3[] boxShape1 = {
            new Vector3(2f, 2f, 2f),
            new Vector3(-2f, 2f, 2f),
            new Vector3(2f, -2f, 2f),
            new Vector3(-2f, -2f, 2f),

            new Vector3(2f, 2f, -2f),
            new Vector3(-2f, 2f, -2f),
            new Vector3(2f, -2f, -2f),
            new Vector3(-2f, -2f, -2f)
    };

    Vector3[] boxShape2 = {
            new Vector3(5f, 5f, 5f),
            new Vector3(-6f, 6f, 8f),
            new Vector3(5f, -5f, 4f),
            new Vector3(-5f, -5f, 5f),

            new Vector3(2f, 2f, -2f),
            new Vector3(-2f, 2f, -2f),
            new Vector3(2f, -2f, -2f),
            new Vector3(-2f, -2f, -2f)
    };

    Vector3[] boxShape = new Vector3[8];

    final float moveTimeSeconds = 3f;
    float totalDelta = 0f;

    public MyScreen() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            boxShape[i] = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
        }

        Color lightColor = new Color(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
        boxMaterial = new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f));

        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));

        //environment.add(new PointLight().set(lightColor, cameraPos, 90.0f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(lightColor, -3f, +3.8f, +3.2f));

        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
        modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        camera3d = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        Vector3 cameraPos = new Vector3( 5f, -19f, 5f);
        camera3d.position.set(cameraPos);
        camera3d.up.set(0f,0f,1f);
        camera3d.lookAt(cameraPos.x,0,cameraPos.z);
        camera3d.near = 1f;
        camera3d.far = 55f;
        camera3d.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        if(boxModel != null){
            boxModel.dispose();
        }

        totalDelta += delta;
        if (totalDelta > moveTimeSeconds) {
            totalDelta = moveTimeSeconds;
        }

        mult = totalDelta / moveTimeSeconds;

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            boxShape[i].x = boxShape1[i].x + (boxShape2[i].x - boxShape1[i].x) * mult;
            boxShape[i].y = boxShape1[i].y + (boxShape2[i].y - boxShape1[i].y) * mult;
            boxShape[i].z = boxShape1[i].z + (boxShape2[i].z - boxShape1[i].z) * mult;
        }

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        modelBatch.begin(camera3d);

        //here, I must to recreate box model each time to get shape needed
        modelBuilder.begin();
        MeshPartBuilder mpb = modelBuilder.part("box", GL30.GL_TRIANGLES,
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, boxMaterial);

        BoxShapeBuilder.build(mpb,
                boxShape[0], boxShape[1], boxShape[2], boxShape[3],
                boxShape[4], boxShape[5], boxShape[6], boxShape[7]);
        boxModel = modelBuilder.end();
        ModelInstance instance = new ModelInstance(boxModel);

        modelBatch.render(instance, environment);

        modelBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        boxModel.dispose();
        modelBatch.dispose();
    }
}
```

I just need to create model once, and then change position of it's vertices and change shape.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You want to start by reading this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Make sure to include all relevant information, including the relevant code.

Comment: @Xoppa, thanks for your attention. I have updated first post with sample code. Hope, it helps to understand, what i want to get in result.

Comment: So you want to animate your model by interpolating it between two poses? That's also called a keyframed cpu animation and was often used in e.g. the md2 file format. Nowadays usually GPU skinning is a better approach, which deforms the model using the GPU instead of the CPU.

Comment: Xoppa, yes, I know about skinning animation. In detail, I have live wallpaper app, it renders 4d hypercube object. There is class, that represents 4d object, and then I make 3d projection of that object. And plans for future - render of more complex objects like 4d sphere, for example. In related topics here I found info about programmatically created Meshes [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042255/adding-a-vertex-to-a-libgdx-mesh?rq=1[/link] . So, I suppose to use them for performance improvement.